# Redmine: can newly created subprojects inherit the members from the parent project?

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins

I'm not sure if this is the correct StackExchange site for this, so I apologize if it's not.

Is it possible to create subprojects in Redmine and have it automatically inherit the member permissions from the parent project? If I've got User A as Manager and User B as Developer on the parent, I'd like it to automagically set that up on the new subproject.

I've searched high and low and can't find a way - internal or plugin - to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's actually very simple: All you have to do is to go into the *administration* panel, display the list of projects, find the *parent* project and use the **copy** button to create the *sub-project*. On the next page you can configure your project, pre-filled with the values of your parent project, and have some more options like copying members.

Of course this works **only on creation** - once you created the sub-project and you change one project, you'll need to change the other one as well. Fortunately, working with groups makes it very easy (configure access for groups, not users).

Comment: This does work, great, thanks! I'm hoping there's another way, though, as well, through the user-side interface. I'd like the same thing to happen with managers creating subprojects, and I don't want to give them administrator access. Thoughts?

Comment: This is not inheritance (as the OP asked) but a certain way to assign individual roles. On the upside, it might solve the problem at hand.

Comment: @Rob This seems only possible as an administrator, sorry.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer as it describes a workaround only available to admins. The OP asked for a way to automatically inherit members from a parent project in newly created projects (by all users). Also see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible now since Redmine [2.3.0](http://www.redmine.org/news/81) (see issue [#5605](http://www.redmine.org/issues/5605) for discussion). When creating (or updating) a project, you can simply check the **Inherit members** checkbox.

[image]

*(This option wasn't available in Redmine when this question was asked and answered initially, so I'd be happy if you considered changing the accepted answer to this one, thanks!)*

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. One of the most fundamental facts of the Redmine permission system is that users are members of distinguished projects having one or more roles. The permissions can't be inherited. In fact, the possibility to have an issue tree was added rather late and hasn't yet been reflected in the permission system.

That said, even if it could be done, permissions could only be added, as you can't take away permissions using roles (permissions from multiple roles are always added). So you would end up with only the possibility to add more permissions in subprojects, but not with less.

Comment: Hrm... Perhaps I used the wrong terminology. I'm not looking to change any individual permissions, all I want is for the same members to be assigned to the subproject, with the same roles, permissions, etc. Still no go?

Comment: Still no. You can always only grant permissions by roles. What I tried to refer to is that the permissions a user has in a certain project comes from the sum of the permissions of all the roles a user has in that specific project. And these roles just can't be inherited now. Also (that's what I theorized about above) even if roles where able to be inherited, it would be rather restricted.